# Share a folder between OneDrive and OneDrive for Business

Tags: onedrive, office-365

I have a personal OneDrive account where I keep a lot of documents. I also have OneDrive for Business through my institution (University), which gives me the more complete version of office online.

Can I share a folder between the two accounts?

When I tried inviting my uni account to the shared folder, I received an email but the folder does NOT appear in my OneDrive for Business.

Answer (score 6):

OneDrive personal and OneDrive for Business are completely different and you can't share folders between these accounts.

You can only generate a link, but you will never see your shared folders in your OneDrive personal account or in your OneDrive for Business account.

Just use only OneDrive for Business or only OneDrive personal otherwise it is not working.

My advice: use a professional cloud storage Service.

Comment: I would tend to agree with you, I've tested it myself, however it doesn't see it in the "Shared with me" section in my OneDrive for Business after sharing it from a regular OneDrive.

Comment: I've had trouble with this so many times even with a shared link.  Sometimes people receive the shared link and can view the files and sometimes they say they can't.  It seems like the clients that have OneDrive business with a corporate network are the ones that can't view shared with everyone links.  It is quite frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can share any folder between two OneDrive accounts. If you don't see the Shared folder on the other account, then please verify the below factors and check if you are missing anything.

1. Check whether the folder is really shared in the 'Shared' > "Shared by Me" option of the left pane from the account where the folder is shared (OneDrive-Personal account). If it is not listing, then there may some issue happened while sharing the folder. Re-share it again
2. Ensure, the other account has minimum of View Only or Can Edit privilege for the folder
3. Hope both are Microsoft accounts and Shared the folder to proper Microsoft account
4. Try share the folder to another account and isolate the issue that it is for any specific account.

Hope these steps would help you.

Comment: Thanks. One of them is not technically a Microsoft account, it's a university account. That is, for login it's redirecting me to the university login page. That could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2020. Just tried recently, it is still impossible to share files between OneDrive and OneDrive business. 
But also tried sharing files between Dropbox and Dropbox business, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it (as of Aug 2020).  After you have set up your business OneDrive account on your machine by installing the OneDrive desktop app, you can now "add an account" to your local machine, by following these steps:

1. left-click the OneDrive icon in the system tray
2. Left-click "More", then left-click "Settings" to open the OneDrive settings window.
3. On the "Account" tab, left-click the "Add an account" button.
4. You will be presented with a login for your personal account. Enter your credentials for you personal OneDrive account here.
5. After clicking next, confirm the path that you want OneDrive to sync to on your local machine. Make sure this is different from your business OneDrive filepath.

Click through the remaining wizard steps, and you are done! In Windows Explorer, you should see 2 OneDrive entries in the treeview.

Answer (score 0):

You can share between personal and business accounts - I'm doing it right now thanks to this forum [(serensat)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/87130/serenesat), adding an account to my personal one through the desktop app and sharing folder from OneDrive for business online.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot share between home and business Microsoft accounts. I wish that this would be made a feature but sadly it is not going to happen in the near future (next 10 years) and by then uni will be over for you. actually it probably already is so this answer is completely useless. sorry.